# How can I deserialize the incoming AWS Lambda request into a lombok @Value or @Data class?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jackson, lombok

If I have a

```
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class IncomingRequest {
    String data;
}
```

and try to have a `RequestHandler` like

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<IncomingRequest, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(IncomingRequest request, Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I only ever get empty `request` objects or with some other configuration I get deserialization exceptions.

What do I need to do to enable AWS Lambda to properly deserialize into my custom class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda uses Jackson to deserialize the data and as such needs a no-arg constructor and setters for the properties. You could make those setters public but at that point you have a mutable class and you generally do not want that for pure data classes. "Luckily" Jackson uses reflection anyway and therefore can (and does) access private methods. Instead of `@Value` you can therefore use

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class IncomingRequest {
    String data;
}
```

That way Jackson can properly parse the incoming JSON and your class remains sort-of immutable. Obviously you can add more constructors via annotation to that class if you want to as long as you make sure a no-args constructor is also still present. Add you can safely add `@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode` as well if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@Jacksonized @Builder` on `IncomingRequest`. Jackson will use that builder to create instances, and your class will remain immutable.

Comment: Results in `com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinition Exception: Cannot construct instance of \`...IncomingRequest\` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)` - I am pretty sure the way AWS deserializes the data is a bit "special".

Comment: The serialisation logic can be found here - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-serialization